# Listening to smart contract events RPC, using web3, on aleth node

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, cpp-ethereum, web3-providers, alethone

bakcground,
I am working on an ethereum based fork of cpp-ethereum/aleth node and not using the official golang client (geth), unfortunately from what I read, websocket support has been 'ditched' in aleth.
Now the problem is, how should we listen to contract events, now that only JSON RPC is available for remote clients?

I am using nodejs with web3 in my client, reading thru the web3 docs, it seems like everything is using websockets as it gives me the error that HTTP Provider does not support listening to events or something.

can somebody help or atleast give pointers on what to do